# Excel compare 2 columns and shift cells down if not same

Tags: excel, compare

I have a large set of data in excel that needs to be matched by column

Before condition is like this

```html
column a    column b
1         1
2         2
3         4
5         5
6         6
8         7
9         9
10         10
14         11
15         12
16         13
17         14
19         15
20         17
         18
         20
```

And I want after condition like this

```html
column a      column b
1            1
2            2
3 
            4
5            5
6            6
            7
8 
9            9
10            10
            11
            12
            13
14            14
15            15
16 
17            17
            18
19 
20            20
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: sorry im newbi, firs post and question but error :D
can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Copy one column and append to it the other. Remove duplicates and sort. If say in ColumnA starting A1 and your data is in two ranges named RangeA and RangeB, in B1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,RangeA,1,0)),"",$A1)
```

in C1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,RangeB,1,0)),"",$A1)
```

copy both down to suit.